# FQL Query that shows me the amount of male and female attendees of a random facebook event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

Well, I have this code here that is a FQL Query that shows me all attendees of an random event from facebook.

```
$fql = "SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = 461462343953933 AND start_time >= now() ORDER BY start_time descLIMIT 50 ";    

$param  =   array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => $fql,
    'callback'  => ''
);

$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);


foreach( $fqlResult as $keys => $values ){
    $start_date = date( 'l, F d, Y', $values['start_time'] );
    $start_time = date( 'g:i a', $values['start_time'] );

    echo "<div style='float:left; display:inline;margin-left:4px;'>";
    echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id={$values['uid']}' target='_blank'><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/{$values['uid']}/picture'></a></div>";   

}
```

However, I need to know how to write a query that shows the amount of male attendees and also the amount of attendees were female from random event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FQL queries are not able to return aggregations. You could use this query

```
select uid, sex from user where uid in (SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid = 461462343953933 AND start_time >= now() ORDER BY start_time desc) LIMIT 50
```

and count the resulting gender info yourself in  your application.